# Why is logcat not showing anything?

Tags: android, logcat

I am using Eclipse classic to develop my Android applications. But I am not able to see any messages in the LogCat. Till yesterday it was showing each and every message, but now it is not showing anything. I have written a lot of log statements to trace my program, but because of this I am not able to trace.

Where is the problem?

Comment: have you cleared the adb logcat command, adb logcat -c?

Comment: I just re-connect my device, It's running.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Try these first

1. Go to the device tab, click your device. and go back to the logcat
   tab
2. You might have filter set.
3. You are probably viewing the wrong package.

Comment: +1 and reloading the Eclipse helped

Comment: Clicking on the device solved it for me.

Comment: This was driving me absolutely mental, cos it was working last night and then not this morning! Thank you!

Comment: Android Studio added a dummy listener interface to one of my fragments when I used the IDE template. This was throwing a class cast exception that was outside my current project filters.

Comment: Package name is correct, Device is correct, I set "no filter" to check if anything is there ... but nothing is getting printed ! I have used Nexus 9 api 17 ARM based emulator ??!?!?!?!?

Comment: Restarting studio has worked for me ...

Comment: None of these 3 tips worked for me. Oh well.

Answer (score 36):

I've got it solved by:

1. Closing the logcat window
2. Running the following in command prompt:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

3. Opening logcat again

Comment: I tried all the above answers, only this works with me, thanks.  Note: Instead of command prompt task manager can be used to kill adb, and then run the app again.

Comment: Cheers. It's only fix that worked for me.

Comment: only this works me. its really frustating.why logs are suddenly not showing. Tried everything. Its was like only at the mercy we can see sometimes. now this solves the problem

Comment: This didn't work for me either (in addition to 1st trying the accepted answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/9529698/2597758)

Answer (score 10):

Every now and then I experience that the logcat output in Eclipse stops showing any logs. It doesn't matter if I unplug and plug the device. It seems like the issue occurs if the logcat gets a ton of messages, and is unable to handle the amount.

The only thing working is restarting Eclipse or use DDMS directly (which also suffers from the same problem).

Answer (score 10):

Go to  Window - Preferences - Android - Logcat .
On that page 
     "Show logcat view if message priority is at least "  select VERBOSE.

[image: Preferences-Android_logcat]

Comment: Please always explain in your answer what this does and how it solves the problem. That would be very helpful.

Comment: This didn't work for me either -- in addition to trying https://stackoverflow.com/a/9529698/2597758 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/20193542/2597758 -- it appears the making LogCat work has lots of preconditions.

Answer (score 9):

This happens when you don't close eclipse for a long duration, just close eclipse and reopen it, your problem should be solved.

Comment: its not resolving yet

Answer (score 7):

Correct answer: it is/was a bug in Eclipse. All I did to trigger it was to rename one of the filter and pressing the Run button.

Restarting Eclipse fixes it.

Answer (score 6):

In eclipse, go to: windows->preferences
Then go to Android->logcat and make sure you have the following setup:
1. double-click action: "go to problem (error line)
2. switch to: java
3. both checkboxes are checked
if your setup is fine, clean the project and restart eclipse
good luck!

Answer (score 4):

Some times it does happen on a slower machine that eclipse waits for emulator HOME screen and after waiting too long it shows that the emulator is offline.
Secondly Make sure that you are looking in the correct filter or in all messages part.

Also you can do the following :

1. select the device and find your process (e.g. "com.android.myapp")
2. Look for its process id written to its left (eg. 17260)
3. Now go to logcat and add a new filter by witting a particular name and the specific Pid (say 17260)
4. Now select that filter and you'l be able to see your log messages

Good Luck!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, but gave up on eclipse logcat panel and switched to cygwin+adb:

1. make sure the app is running and launch cygwin
2. `cd /cygdrive/c/android_sdk/sdk/platform-tools` #go to where adb.exe is
3. [optional] `./adb logcat -c`  #clean the log, obviously don't do this if you want to see some old messages
4. `./adb logcat` #see all messages

or

1. `./adb logcat | grep "whatever"` #look only for whatever you want to look for

Comment: Tried every other solution listed to no avail. Although, I'd still rather it show up in Eclipse logcat panel, at least this command line option gave me access to the info I needed. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to Device from DDMS and open it.
2. Select your device from which device your application is running
3. Select your project which you run on this device

Comment: Steps 1 & 2 are clear enough. Step 3 -- **where** do you "select your project"?

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue for the last few days and tried everything above.

As it turned out, my problem was that all my log statements were in a class that was not being reached. I thought it had because of what was being displayed but that was not the case.

So in short, check with the following

Post log statements at the beginning of every method.

Answer (score 1):

I too had the same problem , and I solved the issue by 
-> restart the eclipse
-> go to ddms -> click on the emulator

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the above solutions, but nothing did work. Then, I saw I had a button named "R", then something clicked in my mind, I renamed it to:

```
R1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

So maybe it was conflicting with R of Android and Java name of a button "R".
Hurray error got resolved.

Let us conclude with the following steps:

1. Check if u have any variable(button,textview) name which is “R”
2. Save your project, close Eclipse and then open it again.
3. Project --> clean
4. import android.R; remove this.
5. Correct answer: it is/was a bug in Eclipse. All I did to trigger it was to rename one of the filter and pressing the Run button. Restarting Eclipse fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

You might have switched off LogCat by Mistake

1. Go to Preferences>Android
2. Click LogCat and make sure there is a check next to "Monitor logcat for messages from applications in workspace"
3. Then select the dropdown "Show logcat view if message priority is at least" and choose "VERBOSE" (or depending on how you tag your Logs, but VERBOSE will get all output)
4. Click "Apply" and you should start seeing your messages again

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you set

```
android:debuggable="true"
```

in your manifest file.

Comment: Warning: `Avoid hardcoding the debug mode; leaving it out allows debug and release builds to automatically assign one.`

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem and the following steps resolved the issue:

1. Restart my Eclipse
2. Restart my Emulator
3. Select devices tab from DDMS perspective in Eclipse.

Comment: Already have good and well accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check the device is not at fault. My device was set not to log, accidentally disabled it via boeffla kernel. After turning it back on logcat worked fine.

Comment: Yes, this could be very well my case, testing on a Mi/Xiaomi.

Answer (score 1):

Go to **windows->preference->android->logcat**

select the option -
**show logcat** if message priority is atleat verbose.

It will show all the events of device and close all the perpestive and open logcat it will be working again.

Comment: Unable to find "Go to windows->preference->android->logcat" on WIndows 10 Android studio 2.1.3 !?!?!?!

Which OS ?

Comment: @Bhuro I used windows 8 and eclipse

Answer (score 0):

On right top corner click on "Display Saved Filter View" or if "display saved filter view" is already open then just click on the red - icon to delete selected logcat filter.