# Logcat messages disappear after a short time

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

Sometimes eclipse logcat messages disappear after closing the app for a short time. (Mostly not so short.) How to make it never disappear automatically?

EDIT: My device is still attached. And how to set it to show log even after device disattach and clear just before next launch?

Comment: when u disconnect device connected or close Emulator it will lose logcat data.... so what exactly is your issue?

Comment: It may be the issue regarding selected device. If you are having more than one device connected, you need to select proper device to view it's logcat. Or your device may be disconnecting.

Comment: That happened with me, I used to clear log my self by clicking red cross button above Once and then it stops cleaning it self automatically.

Comment: It just disappears like this: 1 second, N top item disappears; 2 second, another N top item disappers... Seems controlled by some timer, I don' t know if it' s related to Debug perspective.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

this is also happening with me. The device is attached. And so all the internal actions are getting logged and the error message disappears very quickly. You should try the following (it worked for me)

1. Restart Eclipse (as stated here [Why logcat is not showing anything?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9529628/why-logcat-is-not-showing-anything))
2. if 1 does not work, you may try to increase the logcat message size. From Window > Preferences > Android > LogCat (increase size to more than 5000)

First one worked for me. In this way also you need not to detach the device everytime you deploy the app from eclipse. Regarding, the other question - you can always clear the existing log from [Clear log] button.

Comment: This happens to me too and I'm tired of restarting Eclipse.  Wish they would fix it.  Funny thing is that you see the number of messages increase for that Filter Name, like all Messages.  But when you click on to display it shows a blank panel.  Then click another filter and the messages have increased.  Weird...