# read content from url when incoming call

Tags: java, android

I am trying to find out how to get string from url during incoming call, but it always ends with error "Unfortunatelly stopped". What am I doing wrong?

```
package com.example.detectincomingcall;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;


//import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
//import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MyCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    Context c;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
            // This code will execute when the phone has an incoming call

            // Server Request URL
            String serverURL = "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/getPage.php"; 

            // Create Object and call AsyncTask execute Method
            new LongOperation().execute(serverURL);

            // get the phone number 
            String incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
            String mojText = "";
            if (incomingNumber.equals("+"))
            {
                mojText = "My";
            }
            Toast.makeText(context, "Call from:" +incomingNumber+ " "+mojText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //Toast.makeText(context, "Call from:" +incomingNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
                TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)
                || intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
                        TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
            // This code will execute when the call is disconnected
            Toast.makeText(context, "Detected call hangup event", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }

    // Class with extends AsyncTask class
    private class LongOperation  extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        private final HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        private String Content;
        //private Context context;
        private String Error = null;
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // NOTE: You can call UI Element here.
            Toast.makeText(c, "Idem na internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        // Call after onPreExecute method
        protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {

                // Call long running operations here (perform background computation)
                // NOTE: Don't call UI Element here.

                // Server url call by GET method
                //HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
                String serverURL = "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/getPage.php"; //toto by tu nemuselo byt
                HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(serverURL);
                ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                Content = Client.execute(httpget, responseHandler);

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                Error = e.getMessage();
                cancel(true);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Error = e.getMessage();
                cancel(true);
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
            // NOTE: You can call UI Element here.

            // Close progress dialog            
            if (Error != null) {
                Toast.makeText(c, "msg msg"+Content, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //Toast.makeText(context, "Err:" +Error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(c, "internet internet"+Content, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //Toast.makeText(context, "Internet:" +Content, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();              
             }
        }

    }

}
```

my log file:

```
03-04 13:01:09.381: E/(10486): Device driver API match
03-04 13:01:09.381: E/(10486): Device driver API version: 29
03-04 13:01:09.381: E/(10486): User space API version: 29 
03-04 13:01:09.381: E/(10486): mali: REVISION=Linux-r3p2-01rel3 BUILD_DATE=Tue Jul 22 19:59:34 KST 2014 
03-04 13:01:26.846: E/AndroidRuntime(10486): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-04 13:01:26.846: E/AndroidRuntime(10486): Process: com.example.detectincomingcall, PID: 10486
03-04 13:01:26.846: E/AndroidRuntime(10486): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.example.detectincomingcall.MyCallReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-04 13:01:26.846: E/AndroidRuntime(10486):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2675)
03-04 13:01:26.846: E/AndroidRuntime(10486):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:175)
03-04 13:01:26.846: E/AndroidRuntime(10486):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1384)
03-04 13:01:26.846: E/AndroidRuntime(10486):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-04 13:01:26.846: E/AndroidRuntime(10486):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
03-04 13:01:26.846: E/AndroidRuntime(10486):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
03-04 13:01:26.846: E/AndroidRuntime(10486):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-04 13:01:26.846: E/AndroidRuntime(10486):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-04 13:01:26.846: E/AndroidRuntime(10486):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
03-04 13:01:26.846: E/AndroidRuntime(10486):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
03-04 13:01:26.846: E/AndroidRuntime(10486):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-04 13:01:26.846: E/AndroidRuntime(10486): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-04 13:01:26.846: E/AndroidRuntime(10486):    at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:115)
03-04 13:01:26.846: E/AndroidRuntime(10486):    at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:273)
03-04 13:01:26.846: E/AndroidRuntime(10486):    at com.example.detectincomingcall.MyCallReceiver$LongOperation.onPreExecute(MyCallReceiver.java:68)
03-04 13:01:26.846: E/AndroidRuntime(10486):    at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
03-04 13:01:26.846: E/AndroidRuntime(10486):    at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
03-04 13:01:26.846: E/AndroidRuntime(10486):    at com.example.detectincomingcall.MyCallReceiver.onReceive(MyCallReceiver.java:37)
03-04 13:01:26.846: E/AndroidRuntime(10486):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2660)
03-04 13:01:26.846: E/AndroidRuntime(10486):    ... 10 more
```

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace of the error?

Comment: Can you please give me an example, how to record stacktrace error? (I am a newbie and I used eclipse for this, compilen apk and deployed on my phone, where always "Unfortunately stopped" occurs). Thank you!

Comment: Logcat will show you the stacktrace, which is a record of which methods were executing when the error occurred.  (You can also use Logcat for adding your own log statements...it's useful!)  [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280051/how-to-enable-logcat-console-in-eclipse-for-android) is how you can see the logcat window and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2AHJsRKa_J8) looks like a tutorial.

Comment: thank you, this is for computer. Is there any software I can use on my android? Because I am makeing app and this happens on incoming phone call, so I have no idea how to simmulate it on computer. I tried elogcat for android, but it looks like nothing printed out.

Comment: Logcat works fine with an actual android device, not just with an emulator. You might try one of the many fixes listed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9529628/why-logcat-is-not-showing-anything).  Alternatively, you can use `adb logcat -d > myFileName.txt` from the command line, but you'll need to make sure you have [ADB](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) set up.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got log from my device (I inserted it to main question text).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found what's wrong - I must to change this:

```
            // This code will execute when the phone has an incoming call

            // Server Request URL
```

to this

```
            // This code will execute when the phone has an incoming call

            c = context;

            // Server Request URL
```

Thanks for help with logs guys!