# Eclipse luna logcat not showing error messages

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat, android-logcat

Eclipse logcat window is not showing error messages while compilation of my android project.Displaying only initial albhates.

Comment: Restart your IDE , For better approach switch to Android studio .

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya i see all your solution is switch to Android studio :))
@Sumitra Try restart eclipse. Close Logcat window and re-open it in ``Window -> show view -> Logcat``

Comment: @DanhDC Actually i prefer AS . :) Nice checking .

Comment: #Sumitra May help this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9529628/why-logcat-is-not-showing-anything

Comment: I restarted eclipse,Opened LogCat from Window->show view -> but didn't work.

Comment: @Sumitra Did you check above Link yet ?

Comment: I follwoed the link .. still having the same issue.