# Statement in Catch isn't executed

Tags: java, android

I need to fetch login details from my web service to authenticate login in my app. Below is the code which does the job.

```
      try {
                //Apache Libraries and namevaluepair has been deprecated since APK 21(?). Using HttpURLConnection instead.
                URL url = new URL(wsURL + authenticate);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
                os.write(postParam.getBytes());
                os.flush();
                os.close();

                // Fetching the response code for debugging purposes.
                int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
                Log.d(TAG, "POST Response Code: " + responseCode);

                if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                    String inputLine;
                    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

                    //Adding every responseCode in the inputLine.
                    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        response.append(inputLine);
                    }
                    in.close();

                    Log.d(TAG, "HTTP Response: " + response.toString());
                    //TODO: Check login logic again
                    //Sets Authentication flag
                    if (!response.toString().contains("Authentication Failed!")) {
                        authFlag = true;
                        Log.i(TAG, "Authentication Completed: Logged in Successfully!");
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.toString());
                            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("rows");
                            JSONObject beanObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

                            userBean = new UserBean(username, beanObject.getString("User_FullName"), beanObject.getInt("UserType_Code"));

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error!!! Abort!!!");
                }
                connection.disconnect();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                System.out.println("URLConnection Exception: " + e);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("IOStream Exception: " + e);
            }

            return postParam;
        }
```

Issue I'm facing is I don't see anything related to it in my logcat but on debugging I find that the control goes to 
`} catch (MalformedURLException e) {`
 
but 
`System.out.println("URLConnection Exception: " + e);` 
is never executed. 
I'm novice at Android dev so there might be something which I can't see. Please help.

**EDIT** - I first tried with `Log.e` but it didn't work so I put `System.out.println` which didn't work either.

Comment: For debugging put exception and see if debug point goes inside catch block

Comment: use `Log.e` instead of `System.out.println`

Comment: It does go inside the catch block but the print statement is never executed I tried with Log.e but no luck

Comment: @AshvinSharma How do you know it goes in the catch block if its not logging? Make sure your android studio is set to collect the correct logs(no filtering). Else ensure it does actually error, by calling `throw new IOException("");` or something

Comment: I saw it in the debugger it goes to catch block, I can post a picture if you want. I don't get the last part though, is throwing gonna help?.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use System.out,
instead use logging functions like [logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html) for debugging.

In this example, considering that the catch catches an error, you should use:

```
private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";
...
catch (MalformedURLException e) {
Log.e(TAG, "URLConnection Exception: " + e.getMessage());
                } catch (IOException e) {
Log.e(TAG, "IO error: " + e.getMessage());
                }
```

Here is an explanation of [how to use them properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7959263/android-log-v-log-d-log-i-log-w-log-e-when-to-use-each-one).

If you can't see logcat, go [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9529628/why-logcat-is-not-showing-anything).

Comment: I know how to use Log but it wasn't working so i tried with System.out.println which is not working either

Comment: First System.out does not make sense in android studio programming.
Did you know where is logcat in android?

Comment: yes, it is set on Debug filter but the error won't show with `Log.e(TAG, "URLConnection Exception: " + e);` too

Comment: check the other link

Comment: Yeah No Filters and Debug is selected still no show

Answer (score 0):

just try

> Log.e("tag","Exception: " + e);

and you can find it in android monitor

Comment: `e.printStackTrace();` Would be more ideal to what you are trying

Comment: `e.printStackTrace();` didn't work either

Comment: put a break point on Log.e and if it hit you just need to change the logcat level to "ERROR"

Comment: I did that, and I'm surprised I saw nothing there related to it.

Comment: if you traced it and saw code entered inside of catch  scoop , then this exception has logged and you can find it , even you can search with tag just make sure you have set log-cat to proper level , and if still it doesn't found , with less possibility may be threes something wrong with your IDE , try to clean and rebuild your project

Comment: Yeah I bet there is something wrong either with the IDE or with the emulator, my logcat is full of irrelevant `com.google.android.gms.persistent` errors but not the one I want. I checked all the level Verbose, Debug, Warnings, Errors. I even tried searching but no sign of it.